# how to send additional parameter string with multipart/form-data

Tags: php, android

Trying to upload files to my server with android app, which works fine, but I would like to upload the content to a specific folder (username folder, created if not exists). How would I add that functionality with multiform/form-data?

PHP:

```
<?php
$target_path  = "/home/myfolder/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
" has been uploaded";
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

and (snippet of) current android code:

```
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary); 

    outStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
    outStream.writeBytes(hyph + boundary + end);
    outStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + fileToUpload +"\"" + end);
    outStream.writeBytes(end);
```

Comment: I would not create a folder on an upload form.  Rather, you should consider creating the user folder when the username is created.  Your PHP script should be checking the user's credentials and should, therefore, be able to create the folder if it does not exist using mkdir().  Remember that folders are a convenience for human viewing and there are better ways of doing this when only computers are involved (store the filename in a db with the username, for instance) and fiddling with the filesystem is suboptimal.

Comment: Thats exactly how i am doing it now, saving filenames as reference in a database, and all files are stored in ONE folder, which seems extremely messy. I would believe it would be best to have everything stored in myfolder/username/ so it's easy to compress all files related to username (this is a function on the website, to download all files related to the username). But if so, how would I then add the extra username parameter. (I agree with having the folder created when username is created. :) ) Thanks for your reply.